# insertRowsAtIndexPaths crashes on endUpdates in tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath only if user scrolls quickly

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data

Ok as the title suggests, I am trying to insert more rows in a uitableview when the user scrolls to the bottom of the list. The whole reason is to lazily load the data for performance reasons with a large data set.

The odd thing is that if I scroll slowly then it works fine, but if I scroll quickly then it crashes on  `[tableView endUpdates];`

The datasource is a nsmutablearray which loads data from coredata, using a common fetchRequest. I cannot use a fetchedResultsController in my current circumstances.

The datasource count is correct before and after the insert is called. The row count (and data source count) are correct.

If I scroll slowly and later at some point scroll quickly, it crashes, with usually the same error with the index being beyond the bounds, however the index and bounds in the error message are incorrect with the original counts when the tableview was first bound (and before any insertions occured). Ie row count of 4 and datasource count of 4 & etc.

This is the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
```

I also tried inserting rows during the cellForRowAtIndexPath method but with the same result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not the right way to solve large data set scrolling problems.

1. The `UITableView` is designed to only keep a small number of cells in memory at any one time.
2. Trying to fetch data while scrolling will perform horribly as disk access is significantly slower than UI updates.

Instead you should consider limiting your batch size when fetching your data from Core Data.  Secondarily you should also run instruments against your app and confirm where the hotspots are.  It is highly unlikely that the scrolling or population of cells is the slow point.

BTW, an `NSMutableArray` is rarely useful when dealing with the results from Core Data.  Unless you have a specific reason to have a `NSMutableArray` you should probably change it to a `NSArray`.

Comment: The code which inserts more rows is performing the batch loading from core data. The tableview is reusing the cells as per normal behavior so the number of cells in memory should not be an issue. Your right that an nsmutablearray is not ideal however in this instance it is necessary. Btw I should mention that the number of rows being loaded is small, 10 at a time and the number of existing rows are 10. Which the tableview should easily be able to show.

Comment: The tableview cells are also just the default ones, and I even set the cell text to the row index to see that was the cause but no difference. In instruments, I could not see any hotspots for memory or processor usage up until the app crashes.

Comment: Again this is not the right approach.  Load ALL of the data, let Core Data control the flow of the data using batch size.  Core Data will give you back object references but won't load in all of the data but it will cache the data and your app will perform well.  Have you **tested** the performance before trying to do this?  This *really* comes across as swimming upstream.  I have seen a tableview/coredata handle thousands of rows without an issue.

Comment: The problem lies in that I do not know the total row count of the tableview just from the number of core data objects as I need to check each managed object's date property and then potentially add more objects (which are temporary) in the array. I am working in batches of dates, and using predicates to limit the batch size at the moment. Yes I have tested performance beforehand, and it was not  the greatest, and yes your right that tableviews and core data are able to handle large sets of data (I have done so many times with other apps).

Comment: To clarify, the total rows of the tableview could be infinite, and as the user scrolls, more objects would be added to the nsmutablearray (of which are only temporary). Dates are used to limit the rows/objects. So scroll forward, show next 10 days and etc.

Comment: The more I write the more confusing it seems! The objects in the nsmutablearray are a combination of objects from core data, and new objects which are temporary.

Comment: I've accepted the answer because under most circumstances it is the right approach. I have resorted to using a More button at this stage due to the complexity of the app. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Another solution would be to have *two* `NSPersistentStore` instances; one on disk and one in memory.  As you discover you need to add objects then add them to the in memory store.  From there you can just use a NSFetchedResultsController and that solves your potential memory problems.  Something to consider.

Comment: That is a brilliant idea! I have never used more than one persistent store before. Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Is `NSMutableArray` prepopulated at start of the application? Currently I assume, that you use a controller object as your `UITableViewDelegate` that just returns the final number of rows while the `NSMutableArray` becomes filled up as you move along?

In that case the loading from Core Data might be too slow if you speed up your scrolling resulting in "holes" in the array.

Comment: Yes the nsmutablearray is populated (only with a small batch of data) when the view controller is loaded, but the nsmutablearray count is used for the total row count for the current batch. When the user scrolls and the last row becomes visible, another batch is retrieved and added to the nsmutablearray. The overall total is unknown and could be potentially infinite